# Simple T-SQL Join question

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I am trying to select a record out of the table1 by joining table2 and using table2 columns in the WHERE statement.  Col1 and Col2 in table1 can be stored in col1 of table2.  I need to join col1 of table2 with either the value of col1 or col2 in table1

here is the sql statement I created so (pseudo):

```
SELECT
   t1.Col1,
   t1.Col2,
   t1.Col3,
   t1.Col4
FROM
   table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 on t2.Col1 = t1.Col1 or t2.Col1 = t1.Col2
```

What would be the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That should be fine.  Another way to write the same condition is as follows:

```
... JOIN table2 t2 on t2.Col1 IN (t1.Col1, t1.Col2)
```

It shouldn't matter which way you do it in this case.  Do what you find more readable.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your questoion correctly, your SQL query is perfectly fine.